# itertool and multiprocessing, How can I generate all possible combinations in Parallel

Tags: python, python-2.7, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-itertools

I have the following code which generates all possible combination that produces a given sum (n). This code, however, takes very long for large numbers (n). Is there a way I can parallelize my code across multiple processors?

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

def all_combination(numbers, n):
result = [seq for i in range(n, 0, -1) for seq in combinations_with_replacement(numbers,i) if sum(seq) == n]
return result

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
n=700
print len(all_combination(numbers,n))
```

Comment: Do you understand the basic algorithmic complexities here? The number of combinatons grow exponentially, while multiprocessing can only give you a linear speedup. So simplified and asymptotic: multiprocessing gains you the possibility to increase N by 1 (rounded up!).

Comment: Parallelizing such a process would still take the same time: one processor working at full speed is pretty much the same as two processors each working at half the speed. Multiple processors and concurrent programming (i.e. threads & co) are useful when a part of your program runs faster than another (e.g. code vs user input), not in cases like this.

Comment: I was thinking if one list can handle generating half of the list and the other will handle the other half.

Comment: The most simple approach would be doing the first 1 or 2 steps (branchings) manually and run the remaining in parallel. But as i said: it's wasted work for 99.9% of all scenarios.

Comment: @MohamadIbrahim that's certainly possible using threading or similar modules, though I'm a bit out of practice to help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import product
import math
import multiprocessing

def parallel_combination(i, limit):
    numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    result=0
    for seq in combinations_with_replacement(numbers, i):
        if sum(seq) == limit:
            result+=1
    return result

def chunks(min_value, max_value):
    for i in range(max_value, min_value, -1):
        yield i

if __name__ == "__main__":
    max_value=610
    limit=610
    min_value=int(math.floor(float(limit/6)))
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    n_processesor=32
    chunk_size=int((math.ceil(float((max_value-min_value))/n_processesor)))
    processes = pool.map(func=parallel_combination, limit, iterable=chunks(min_value,max_value), chunksize=chunk_size)
   final_result=0
   for process in processes:
        if process:
            final_result+=process
    print final_result
```